# Assembly Language Absolute addresses and segment registers

Tags: assembly, stack, segment

a review problem lists these registers in hex:

```
cs = ????  sp = 0300  ax = a66a  ip = 01cf
ds = 4100  bp = 0003  bx = 1234  
ss = 48ee  si = 0100  cx = 00ff
es = 4cee  di = 1000  dx = 0000
```

1. The absolute address of the next instruction to be executed is 40f0f.

   ```
   40f0f  
   -01cf
   _____
   40d40 / 10 = 40d4 = cs
   ```
2. Is the size of the data segment in bytes always equal to the stack segment minus the data segment * 10? 48ee - 4100 =  7ee0. Likewise, is the code segment in bytes always equal to the data segment minus the code segment * 10? 48ee - 40d4 = 81a0.
3. For `mov cx,[bx + si]`, the absolute address of the source operand is 42334.

   ```
   bx = 1234
   si = 0100
   _________
        1334

   ds = 4100 * 10 = 41000 + 1334 = 42334
   ```
4. For `mov cx,[di - 4]`, the absolute address of the source operand is 41ffc.

   ```
   di = 1000
        -  4
   _________
        0FFC

   ds = 4100 * 10 = 41000 + 0ffc = 41ffc
   ```
5. For `mov cx,[bp + si - 3]`, the absolute address of the source operand is 48fe0.

   ```
   bp = 0003
   si = 0100
         - 3
   _________
        0100

   ss = 48ee * 10 = 48ee0 + 0100 = 48fe0
   ```

Am I going about solving these the right way? How do I know when to use the stack segment for these calculations and when to use the data segment?

Comment: Really? Someone's still teaching these antiquated concepts? Segmentation died out years ago, unless you're operating in embedded space, I guess, or you're taking some sort of Computer History class :-)

Comment: Assembly language seems close enough to a computer history class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For address calculations involving `bp` or `sp` or stack operations like `push` or `pop` the segment register is implicitly `ss`, for other addresses `ds`. Exception: If you use a string instruction, the destination segment register is implicitly `es`.