# Measuring the size of data and code segments in ASM

Tags: assembly, masm32

I am looking for a way to efficiently calculate the data and code segments in my program for an assignment.

I looked around and found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486780/assembly-language-absolute-addresses-and-segment-registers) but it did not seem to yield the answer I was looking for. When DS is subtracted from CS (values read via my debugger) I got 2h which times 10 would be 20h though the actual code segment is 23h according to the listing I got from masm.

One way I found to figure out the size of the code segment was to get EIP toward the end of the program by calling a small snipet of code that would put EIP on the stack briefly before returning.

Although this works it adds roughly 10 bytes to the code segment and i'll have to accommodate for all instructions that happen after the call specifically _end and add. I would like a more efficient or at least an absolute way of getting the size of the code segment if possible.

As for the data segment, I haven't had or found any good ideas yet. When running my program in the debugger my DS and SS were the same for whatever reason. Still very new at this so I'm not sure why that is.
I appreciate any suggestions.

EDIT added code (10/1/2014)

```
INCLUDE Pcmac.inc
.MODEL  SMALL
.586
.STACK  100h

.DATA
MsgX DB 'Please enter a name: ', '$'
MsgY DB 10,13,'You entered: ', '$' 

BufferP     DB 26 ;25 char + Return
StringSize  DB 0
String      DB 26 DUP (0) ;Buffer Space


.CODE
```

Hello   PROC

```
    _Begin

    _PutStr MsgX

    _GetStr BufferP

    lea bx, String      ;load address of buffer into bx (Has to be an index or base register)
    mov ax, 0           ;0 out ax
    mov al, StringSize  ;move the size of the string into al (can be any register)

    add bx, ax          ;add the size of string to it's address, 
                        ;we now have the address of the carriage ret (String + StringSize) in the bx register

    mov ax, '$'         ;move a character to ax (the character you wish to replace the carriage ret with)
    mov [bx], ax        ;mov ax or '$' to the location bx is pointing toward 

    _PutStr MsgY
    _PutStr String


    _Exit
```

Hello  ENDP

```
    END Hello
```

Comment: Nobody said segments can't overlap.  To access the 24h'th byte which is in the next segment, the corresponding segment register must be 2

Comment: Note: 2h x 10 = 14h. 2h x 10h = 20h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to the question I had, I got to this point with a help from a friend.

```
INCLUDE Pcmac.inc
.MODEL  SMALL
.586
.STACK  100h

.DATA
StartData DB 0

MsgX DB 'Please enter a name: ', '$'
MsgY DB 10,13,'You entered: ', '$' 


BufferP     DB 26 ;25 char + Return
StringSize  DB 0
String      DB 26 DUP (0) ;Buffer Space

DataSize    DB 10, 13, '.Data = ', '$'
CodeSize    DB 10, 13, '.Code = ', '$'


EndData     DB 0
distance    dw EndData-StartData+03h ;add 3h to include distance pointer plus a mystery 
                                     ;byte that was calculated by the masm listing


.CODE
EXTERN PutHex : NEAR

GetIP:  mov eax, [esp]  ;getting ip at a point is technically a way of getting the 
                        ;amount of bytes offset from the beginning of the program
        ret

 Hello   PROC

    _Begin

    _PutStr MsgX

    _GetStr BufferP

    mov bx, 0
    lea bx, String
    mov ax, 0
    mov al, StringSize
    add bx, ax
    mov ax, '$'
    mov [bx], ax

    add bx, ax


    _PutStr MsgY
    _PutStr String

    _PutStr DataSize
    mov ax, distance ;mov the value at distance into ax
    call PutHex      ;print the hex value in ax

    _PutStr CodeSize
    call GetIP          ;pushes the address of the next instruction onto the stack and 
                        ;places it in ax

    add ax, 0Ah         ;adding 18h to include the bytes used after the GetIp call
    call PutHex         ;print the hex value in ax

    _Exit
    Hello   ENDP

    END Hello
```

The distance pointer holds the value of the difference between EndData and StartData. Effectively giving you the size of the data segment. You must add 03h (based on the masm listing) to the final answer 02h being the word 'Distance' and 01h unaccounted though i'm adding since the listing showed a 3h difference.

For the size of the code segment I used a small function labeled getIp; When a function is called the offset of the next instruction is pushed onto the stack allowing us to put it into ax within the function before returning. This offset is essentially the size of the code segment between the first instruction 0000 and the one following the call to getip. In this case you must add 0Ah to the result in order to include all the instructions following the getip call.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to tell us in which operating mode the CPU is:

The thread you are linking to is obviously talking about "real mode" (as it is used while booting the operating system or by systems like MS-DOS). In real mode the absolute address is calculated using 10h*segment+offset.

Because you are talking about "EIP" and not about "IP" I assume that your program is a 32-bit program and you are using "protected mode".

All 32-bit and some 16-bit operating systems use this mode. In this mode the segment registers contain "selectors" which are indexes into a table which contains the base address of a segment as well as the access rights. Because the selectors in CS and SS must have different access rights (CS must have "execute" rights and SS must have "write" rights) these two registers will never have the same value in protected mode.

This means that you cannot calculate any sizes or offsets from the values in the segment registers because they are simply indexes into that table...

Most modern 32-bit operating systems use "flat memory layout" which means that there are only two selectors for a program (in Windows: 23h for CS and 2B for DS, ES and SS) that point to the same memory (but have different access rights).

In MS-DOS programs (real mode) DS and ES typically point to the PSP while CS and SS are initialized according to the header of the EXE file.

Comment: After reading over some more info I would say you're right on the money. I'm still not totally sure about the operating mode since we haven't gone over that yet but from what I read so far It would be safe to assume i'm running protected mode and it is a 32 bit program. If trying to calculate the size of the Data and Code segments are unrealistic would you suggest I look into having my program run in real mode?

Comment: First of all you have to define what the "size of a segment" is. Typically using the values in the segment registers will not give you any useful information - not even in real mode. Without knowing what exactly you want to do nobody can give you more information.

Comment: I appreciate your patience, here is a snippet of code I would like to use as an example. In this code I would like to calculate the amount of space that is being used in .Code and .Data; I can do this already with the listing file but I would like to know how I could have my program calculate these values itself if possible. So far the only solution I've gotten for .code was to call a function that when eip is pushed onto the stack, can be moved to a register before returing. This works since generally EIP starts at zero within my simple programs.